# NullReferenceException after querying database using ToAsyncList() but not when ToList() is used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, nullreferenceexception

I am building a ToDo list app with ASP.NET Core Razor Pages and I am using EF Core.

I have a model that is ToDo

```
public class ToDo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
}
```

Heres PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ToDo> ToDos { get; set; }

    // constructor and DI code omitted 

    public async void OnGet()
    {
        ToDos = await _context.ToDos.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Here's razor page that uses this:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<div>
    @foreach(var todo in Model.ToDos)
     {
        <h4>@todo.Title</h4>
        <p>Is Completed: @(todo.IsCompleted ? "Yes" : "No")</p>
     }
</div>
```

When I visit this page I get `System.NullReferenceException` at `Model.ToDos`

However, when I change OnGet method to use `ToList()` instead:

```
public void OnGet()
{
    ToDos = _context.ToDos.ToList();
}
```

Everything works perfectly.

Why can't I use `ToListAsync()`

Comment: Look for `OnGetAsync` instead...

Comment: You should at least change `public async void OnGet()` to `public async Task OnGet()`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever still throws the exception even when OnGetAsync is used.

Comment: @phuzi why do you recommend that?

Comment: Avoid async void - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        ToDos = await _context.ToDos.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: this actually works ! Can you please explain why my approach is wrong and this approch is correct. I am new to C#.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void

Comment: Like @phuzi link. Async and Await is quite a big topic.  My personal rule is that any method that is calling an async method should be an async method and the return type should be Task or Task<returntype> where return type can be a string, int, object and etc. You should always await your async method unless you intend to call an async method and do something else and later in the code await the result.  Please youtube a few video's on "async await c#" to have a better understanding.